# Transfer two pets from China to India

Tags: dogs

I have two pets: one golden retriever, age 3.5 years and one Labrador, age 1.5 years. Now, we are planning to move from China to India. I read the travel documents and vaccine issues. However, the main challenge is I am afraid of the distance (there is no direct flight, two flight changes, and by road). This is the first time for my dogs with flight. I am wondering what are the possible ways to tackle these issues. My golden retriever is very sensitive, I am too worried about him.

Comment: Equal which way they will relocate, you can start to train them with a transport box (if you not already do so). They have to know: this is a save place, all sounds, smells and so on from outside do not harm them. So they can be relaxed (as relaxed as they can) when be transported with car/airplane. There are some questions here, about to train with a transportation box / dog crate

Comment: @Allerleirauh  thank you. I’m wondering will it be fine for them to travel 15 hours (including all break journey)? Is there any general guidelines?

Comment: I am not a dogs person, but there is a question about long trip with a car: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/511/what-strategy-to-undertake-for-a-long-car-trip-with-my-dog

Comment: I understand your worries. My last intercontinental move with my dogs [1 of which too big for cabin] was a 2-leg one, but I stayed I 3 nights in the intermediate destination. We were OK. [Luckily your dogs are still young, mine were ca 10 years then]. Still, if possible [e.g. if one can still avoid the quaranteens for the dogs in the intermediate flight stops] I would certainly consider to do the 3-leg flight marathon "one leg at a time", i.e. stay for 1-2 nights in both places. Esp, if the 1st flight is not the longest one of the 3, might help as "training" for the latter ones.

Comment: @Tuomo I am too worried. Hope your words can give me some confidence. I am wondering what are the precautions you took? For example, height, air pressure, speed of the flight.

Comment: @user199 Sorry if I made you worried. Just looking at facts, if your dogs are of that age, if they are resonably healthy in general, the trip is to a high likelihood going to be unpleasant, but not dangerous. So, my comments were more considering I am also too worrying + just to give hints what I think might make the trip less unpleasant. Anyway: No need to worry about the pressure, temperature etc in the animal cargo department, they are OK. [Depending on the temperature at the airport during possible flight changes is probably more relevant, as you go from China to India].

Comment: @Tuomo thank you again. The shortest route has a flight layover 8 hours, and flight hours for two fight are: 4 and 6 hours.